# Should i repeat the preposition “of” when using it with “and” in a phrase’s subject?

Tags: prepositions, verb-agreement, prepositional-phrases, compound-subjects

Original Phrase: Absence of puberty and development of secondary sexual characteristics is suggestive of hypogonadism.”

Structures:

Original: “Absence of X and Y is suggestive of Z”

Alt: “Absence of X and of Y is suggestive of Z”

Alt’: “Absence of X and absence of Y are suggestive of Z”

Which way is correct? When i first read it i wrongly assumed that the author meant “Absence of X and Presence of Y”.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I think the extra *of* is required there to exclude the erroneous reading you mention. Including the *of* before *development* forces the connection back to *absence*.

Other possibilities -
absence of X along with absence of Y
absence of X and its development of Y
absence of X and lack of development of Y

Comment: +1 to be clear, the "of" is required if you want to remove the ambiguity, but is not strictly required for grammar. The original sentence is grammatically correct and natural as it stands, but not good semantically because it could be read to have the opposite meaning.